Does SQLite support ALL and ANY keywords?
Does SQLite support ALL and ANY keywords?
I keep facing syntax error while using them.
SELECT name, price
FROM products
WHERE price > ALL (
    SELECT price FROM products WHERE category = 'Electronics'
    );`

I can get what I want using a different approach. I want to know can I use ALL or ANY.
I tried using ALL to get name and price of the products that have a higher price than all products with category 'Electronics'.

This question is similar to: SQLite syntax for "ALL". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

When you look at the list of supported functions in the SQLite documentation, do you see those functions? If not, then they're not supported.

I see ALL but I get syntax error while I try to use it.
I even check it with chatgpt and I get error again

SQLite does not directly support the ALL and ANY keywords.
While SQLite does have an ALL keyword, it's used in a different context, specifically for selecting all rows from a table. It's not used in comparison operations like in other SQL dialects.
you can achieve similar functionality like you used (>).
  SELECT * FROM table1
    WHERE column1 > (SELECT MAX(column1) FROM table2);

